# New "Open PDF" App

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, xiaomi, pdf

I have a POCO F3 Xiaomi phone not rooted.

Recently when I try to open a PDF file from the WhatsApp, in the list of apps able to open it (Drive, Dropbox PDF viewer, Word, ... are the choices), there is a new app called Open PDF. I never installed it and I can't find it in the settings. So I cannot uninstall it.

I'm worrying.
Is it a virus? How to uninstall it?

Note: As @Robert asked in comment, I have a System apps Updater, I think from Xiaomi. This updater appears to modify my default settings and installs apps against my will.
Now I am almost sure that this app is from **CamScanner**.

Comment: Have you installed a system update recently?

Comment: @Robert yes, I think from Xiaomi

Comment: Than congratulate yourself. You have a new bloatware from your OEM to enjoy. If you want to know when this app was installed and where this is a system app you can use [App Manager](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.muntashirakon.AppManager/) app to find those details.

Comment: @Firelord you recommend to remove it?   I have bitdefender and I see no alert

Comment: I suggest that you investigate whether its installation/update time coincides with the time you updated your device or system apps. Once you identify the source of this app (that is to say -- what installed it in your device), you can decide whether to keep it or remove/disable it. // Antivirus apps are mostly useless in Android against the kind of threat this app may pose (if it decides to go rogue). You can't rely on these antivirus apps in Android.

Comment: @Firelord I checked, this app is not in the updates. But a fue weeks ago, some documents, texts or PDF were possible to open only with Xiaomi apps and I uninstalled them, links also were opened only by mi browser. I uninstalled the mi browser and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Netguard firewall, apart from being a firewall it also lists down all the apps (both system and installed) on your phone, find that pdf app you are concerned about , copy the package name (it looks something like com.blah.bla.openpdf), then, go to your pc, install platform tools from google, enable developer options on your phone, enable usb debugging, connect your phone to pc using usb cable, open command prompt in the platform tools folder you downloaded (extract the zip after downloading), write `adb devices` , this will prompt you to allow usb debugging on your phone, allow it, then write `adb uninstall <package name>`  and then you should see “success”. The app will then be gone, do this for all the bloatware apps that you don’t like. Just make sure that you don’t remove certain xiaomi apps such as the security app, it will break your phone.